# Django, is manual caching a bad idea?

Tags: database, django, caching

Some of my reports are taking far too long. I've implemented some "cache" fields to solve the problem. For example a student's GPA is a fairly involved calculation. I've add a non normalized gpa field to student. On each grade update, the GPA is recalculated and so it can always be assumed the GPA field is current.

I know there are a number of caching mechanisms in Django. Am I correct that they wouldn't be able to do this?

Comment: Could a periodic cronjob that goes through and calcs the GPAs help??

Comment: Thought of that, wouldn't work because people often want a grade report right after entering grades.

Answer (score 1):

You could work around your problem using Django's cache framework, but you'd go about things differently. You can certainly cache anything you want with it, but it's not designed to save results on an object. If you want to avoid calculating the GPA and still be able to access it off each model instance the way you are going about it is simple and probably the best way to do it.